# Trouble creating a chart in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have the following 2-column data (taken from a csv file) that I want to use in a chart in excel. Problem is that when I create the chart, it just creates an empty one even if I have selected the values and only y-axis has the numbers from 0.0 to 1.0. Changed the decimal point to dot instead of comma and still the same.

```
0.1 0.000  
0.2 0.000  
0.3 0.000  
0.4 0.001  
0.5 0.006  
0.6 0.018  
0.7 0.040  
0.8 0.079  
0.9 0.190  
1.0 7.159
```

Comment: Which version of Excel, and which OS?

Comment: I'm sorry. Windows 7 professional and office 2007.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

If the spacing of the X values is uniform (it looks like it is) then select just the right hand column and insert the chart of the type you want. Then right click on the chart and click Select Data. Under Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels click the edit button. Select the left hand column as the Axis Label range.

The second way is to select both columns of data and then select a chart type of X/Y scatter. That should insert the chart exactly as you want. A scatter chart is slower for large sets of data but will work with data that isn't at a fixed spacing on the X axis.

Comment: The third way is to put a blank cell above the first X value and a label above the first Y value. Select the two columns including this new row and insert the chart. The blank cell helps Excel parse the data into X and Y values.